# RSpec and ThinkingSphinx returns no results

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, thinking-sphinx

Creating a record with FactoryGirl, but the search() method on that records class returns nothing. I can confirm the record does exist in the DB with a find().

Nothing I've found seems to be working. Have tried setting this up following standard thinking_sphinx and rspec documentation. Included is my rails_helper, spec_helper, spec and it's output. Anyone guidance is much appreciated.(Note: I removed quite a bit from these files to leave just enough to reproduce the error)

The Spec...

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe SiteController do

  before(:each) do
    @article = create(:article)
  end

  describe "GET index" do
    it "assigns and renders articles" do
      get :index
      assert_equal assigns(:articles), [@article]
    end
  end
end
```

It's output...

```
1) SiteController GET index assigns and renders articles
Failure/Error: assert_equal assigns(:articles), [@article]
Minitest::Assertion:
--- expected
+++ actual
@@ -1 +1 @@
-[]
+[#<Article id: 1, title: "Article Title", header_one: "Article      Header One", header_two: "Article Header Two", url: "http://www.testurl.com", description: "This is a test article!", body: "This is the article body.", photo_file_name: "test_image.png", photo_content_type: "image/png", photo_file_size: 96884, photo_updated_at: "2015-03-06 23:55:39", delta: true, user_id: 1, category_id: nil, posted_at: nil, created_at: "2015-03-06 23:55:40", updated_at: "2015-03-06 23:55:40">]
```

rails_helper.rb...

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require 'spec_helper'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
end
```

spec_helper.rb...

```
require 'devise'

module SphinxHelpers
  def index
    ThinkingSphinx::Test.index
    # Wait for Sphinx to finish loading in the new index files.
    sleep 0.25 until index_finished?
  end

  def index_finished?
    Dir[Rails.root.join(ThinkingSphinx::Test.config.indices_location, '*.{new,tmp}*')].empty?
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.raise_errors_for_deprecations!

  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
  config.include SphinxHelpers

  config.before(:suite) do

    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)

    ThinkingSphinx::Test.init
    ThinkingSphinx::Test.start_with_autostop
  end

  config.around(:each) do |example|
    DatabaseCleaner.cleaning do
      example.run
    end
  end

  config.before(:each) do |example|
    index # if example.metadata[:js]
  end

  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Thx @pat for the push in the right direction. The issue does appear related to the following

```
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
```

Changing that to just the following seems to work right now

```
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
#DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
```

(Shocking that the line declaring transaction is related to my problems with transactions :) )

I pulled those lines initially from the database cleaner rspec instructions and thought the clean_with declaration is what would be used when using the cleaning block. Clearly not understanding something there, but can investigate that separately. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling `index` (from `SphinxHelpers`) anywhere in your spec - so, Sphinx is never updated with your new record.

Add `index` at the end of your `before(:each)` block and see if that helps.

Comment: Hey pat, thx for the response. Had the same thought myself, but index() should be called for each spec via the before(:each) in the spec_helper? Tracing through the entire test run with a debugger confirmed I'm hitting the index. Have even tried explicitly calling index with the thinking sphinx helper method after the create(). In looking through the logs, it still seems like the test is being run in a transaction, but can't figure out why that's still happening.

Comment: This line probably is the culprit: `DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction`. Also: `index` needs to be called _after_ you create your objects - so the `before(:each)` block in your `spec_helper` isn't going to be helpful, as I'd expect it would be invoked before the `before(:each)` blocks specific to each test.

Comment: The delta indexing should take care of any changes that occur after an explicit index. Regardless, I've tried putting index calls throughout the code with no luck. Agree the transaction statement looks suspect, but changing it isn't having any affect unfortunately.